# How to get Bootstrap table data and delete the row

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, ejs

This is a part of my ejs file. assume that, there is bootstrap table as below.

What I want to do is that, if I press a button, my del() function will be executed for selected row deletion. But it's not working.
my function even don't get the 'row.data'

How do I get the row.data and delete a row based on the row.data?

```
 $('#table').bootstrapTable({
               columns: [{
                      field: 'no',
                      title: 'No',
                      align: 'center',
                      valign: 'middle',
                      sortable: true
                  }, {
                      field: 'seq',
                      title: 'rank',
                      align: 'center',
                      valign: 'middle',
                      sortable: true
                  }, {field: 'title',
                      title: 'name',
                      align: 'center',
                      valign: 'middle',
                      sortable: true }, [
                  ]data: [{
                      id: 1,
                      no: 1,
                      seq:1,
                      title: 'Test 1',

                  },{
                      id: 2,
                      no: 2,
                      seq: 2,
                      title: 'Test 2',
                     }]
                    });

function del(){

   var $table = $('table');
   var ids = $.map($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
        console.log("checked");
        return row.data;
   });
   console.log("Ids : " + ids);

  $('#table').bootstrapTable('remove', {
       index : 1
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the # sign in del function. It should be-

```
var $table = $('#table');
```